# "Seine Haare sind braun."

Tags: sentence-structure, grammaticality

"Seine Haare sind braun." sounds a little weird in English. Word-for-word it translates to "His hairs are brown.".

Is there another gentle way of saying this in German?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this German sentence.

Comment: Learning a foreign language you must break a habit of mot-a-mot translation.

Comment: I thought there was a typo in Duolingo app

Comment: The same goes for "The police are coming" - sounds weird to the German ear :-)

Comment: Die Polizei sind kommen ? @ThorstenDittmar ?

Comment: No. "Die Polizei kommt". Just another example for expressions that can not be translated word by word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could alternatively use "Seine Haarfarbe ist braun". Though that's more impersonal and not really used much. I would stick with "Seine Haare sind braun", even if it might sound a bit weird to you.

Comment: I actually needed 2 years to understand that one should not learn German by translating German phrases/words to English, instead look for German synonyms